# .Net Classified Advertisement Application with Source

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before I roll my own, can anyone recommend a good .Net C# classified ad system w/payment option(s) + source code? I can't find anything out there worth anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say probably Microsoft's own:

[ASP.NET Classifieds Site Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/classifieds/)

would be your best bet.  Not sure if it includes payment options, but it shouldn't be too hard to add your own using something like Paypal.  An example for that can be found here:

[Integrating PayPal Payments into E-Commerce Applications with ASP.NET](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/PayPalIntegration/PayPalIntegration.asp)